# Creating a JavaFX count-down timer

Tags: java, javafx

I am in deep-need of a simple JavaFX8 count-down timer. I was unable to find much help from other sources.

I just need to it to take a variable (in minutes) and have it countdown to zero.

What is the most simplest way this can be done?

Comment: What have you attempted? (I can't asked "What have you tried", but asking "What have you attempted" works? What a joke..)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/animation/Timeline.html) with a single `KeyFrame` at one minute with [an event handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.event.EventHandler-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-). In the event handler, decrement the counter, and set the [`Timeline`'s cycle count](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setCycleCount-int-) to the number of minutes.

Comment: This one could help as it takes James_D approach http://www.asgteach.com/blog/?p=334

Answer (score 0):

You should try and use a [`Task`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). As luck would have it, the javadoc for it also comes with code examples, including one that sleeps.

With this, you should be set.